# e.Cancel does not work

Tags: c#

I have VS 2010 and want to cancel the form closing event via a Yes|No|Cancel dialog, but when I put the e.Cancel in the event handler for the dialog box, I get an error that says "'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Cancel' and no extension method 'Cancel' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)." Also the word "Cancel" has a red line under it. Everything I've read online says this is the only way to cancel a FormClosing event. I tested the code in VS2008 and it does the same thing.

The code for the event handler is below:

```
private void displayMessageBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes to the document before closing it?", "MyNotepad",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            rtbMain.Clear();
            this.Text = "Untitled - MyNotepad"; 
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            // Leave the window open.
            e.Cancel() = true;


        }
```

Here are the usings (in the event it makes a difference):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
```

Comment: `Cancel` is not a method call it is a property.  Read the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx

Comment: In case you didn't get what @asawyer is saying just do `e.Cancel = true;` with no brackets.

Comment: @EdS. if his code compiled he wouldn't be here.

Comment: I tried the e.Cancel with and without the parentheses and it throws the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [FormClosing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) has [its own EventArgs subclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx), which you should be taking as a parameter to your event handler:

```
private void displayMessageBox(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes to the document before closing it?", "MyNotepad", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        rtbMain.Clear();
        this.Text = "Untitled - MyNotepad"; 
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        // Leave the window open.
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Further, `e.Cancel` is a property, and you're calling it as one would a method. The parentheses need to be removed.

Answer (score 5):

[Form.FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) uses a `FormClosingEventArgs` instead of just `EventArgs`.

You need to use:

```
private void displayMessageBox(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
```

If you use the older [Form.Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) event, instead, it is defined as a `CancelEventHandler`, which uses `CancelEventArgs`, not `EventArgs`.

```
private void displayMessageBox(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
```

Using either of these, you can then do:

```
 e.Cancel = true;
```

Comment: Yes, that will work too. Actually it's a `FormClosingEventArgs` object, but that inherits `CancelEventArgs`.

Comment: It says in the question that it's a `FormClosing` event.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the `FormClosingEventArgs` type in the method signature:

```
private void displayMessageBox(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
```

and:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

Or cast the reference to access it as that type:

```
((FormClosingEventArgs)e).Cancel = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is very easy >>**

**Use *FormClosing* Event:**

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    displayMessageBox(this, e);
}

private void displayMessageBox(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes to the document before closing it?",
                                            "MyNotepad", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
         saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
           rtbMain.Clear();
        this.Text = "Untitled - MyNotepad";
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        // Leave the window open.
        e.Cancel = true;


    }

}
```